# Realtime connection (SockJS/Socket.io) and Microservice application

Tags: session, socket.io, real-time, microservices, sockjs

Currently I'm building an application in a micro service architecture.

The first application is an **API** that does the user authentication, receive requests to initiate/keep a realtime connection with the user (via Socket.io or SockJS) and the system store the socket id into the User object.

The second application is a **WORKER** doing some stuff and sometime he has to send realtime data to the user.

The question is: How should the second application (the **WORKER**) send realtime data to the user?

Should the **WORKER** send a message to the API then the **API** forward this message to the user? 
Or the **WORKER** can directly send the message to the user?

Thank you

Comment: In the first scenario the user would need an active socket connection with both APi, and worker.  In the second, it would only require one to API.  Also, if the worker could send directly to the user, you would most likely need to duplicate all the user auth and management on both the API and Worker.

Comment: Finally I've implemented a third service handling all websockets connections. Then the API and Workers can send websockets message by using the internal pubsub system to communicate with the Websocket service.

Answer (score 1):

In a perfect world example, the service that are responsible to send "publish" a real time push notifications should be separated from other services. Since the micro service is a set of narrowly related methods, and there is no relation between the authentication "user" service, and the realtime push notification service. And to a deep break down, the authentication actually is a separate service, this only FYI, There might be a reason you did this way.

How the service would communicate? There is actually many ways how to implement the internal communication between the services, MQ solution, which could add more technology to your stack, like Rabbit MQ, Beanstalk, Gearman, etc...

And also you can do the communication on top of HTTP protocal, but you need to consider that the HTTP call will add more cost.

The perfect solution is that each service will have to interfaces to execute on their behalf, HTTP interface and an MQ interface (console)